# How to take a screenshot in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

So I have a DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid inside of a PhoneApplicationPage, in my WP8 app; and I would like to take a screenshot. As far as I can tell (from google), there isn't a call to simply "take a screenshot". What people are doing is using a WriteableBitmap, like this:

```
WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(test, null);
wbmp.SaveJpeg(isoStream2, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
```

I have tried test as both the DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid, and the PhoneApplicationPage. Neither of these are working for me. Could it have something to do with the fact that I am rendering everything using RenderTargets and pixel shaders (in SharpDX)? I just get a black image. Here is the code to save the image:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream2 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("new.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoStore))
{
    WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(test, null);
    wbmp.SaveJpeg(isoStream2, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
}
```

But like I said, it just creates a black image.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the WriteableBitmap constructor actually copy the image, or just create a bitmap with equivalent properties. Could be that you need to copy the bitmap before saving?

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure. If I go in and look at the WriteableBitmap.Pixels array, it is just all black though...it seems like it is, however, creating an appropriately sized image..

Comment: What is test?  try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837148/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-full

Comment: Tried your code as is with the exception of changing "test" to root grid, in my app x:Name="LayoutRoot", and works fine! What does "test" refer to anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code as is with the exception of changing *"test"* to the name of the root grid, in my app `x:Name="LayoutRoot"`, and works fine! Just replace *test* with the element you want to capture, the root-grid name for whole page or sub element name for just that element.

---

BTW thanks for the code, one more to squirrel away.

Comment: Test is a PhoneApplicationPage. I have also tried it as the DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid that my Effect renders to, but that just leaves it black - as does the LayoutRoot. Thanks for the reply tho :)

Comment: I am sorry as it is my fault because I did not read your question with due care and used the code successfully only with a PhoneXamlDirect3DApp NOT using the project type you described.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the code below. Though it is saving to the Media Gallery.

```
WriteableBitmap bmpCurrentScreenImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
bmpCurrentScreenImage.Render(LayoutRoot, new MatrixTransform());
bmpCurrentScreenImage.Invalidate();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Save the picture to the Windows Phone media library.
    bmpCurrentScreenImage.SaveJpeg(stream, bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelWidth, bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var picture = new MediaLibrary().SavePicture(name, stream);
    return picture.GetPath();
}
```